# Crucial MX500 SSD Win7/Win10/Cloned Win7 unusual boot issue

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

I just bought a Crucial MX500 500gb SSD and wanted to install two operating systems on it. However, no matter what I do (install Win7, Win10, clone Win7) the OS won't boot from that drive (I could boot to a system through the bootable USB). I suspect the problem lies in one of the following:

1. Faulty drive.
2. BIOS problem
3. Boot problem

I have no idea which one it may be, so I'll explain what I did and what results it brought me. So far I've been at it a total of 12 hours, non-stop, so the early details are a bit hazy. After some point, most of the images were created using [Rufus 2.18](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). I have two cables that attach the drives and I'd sporadically switch between them.

**IN ALL CASES, IF NEEDED, I CAN REPEAT ALL THESE STEPS TO EXACTLY IDENTIFY THE RESULTS AND TAKE PICTURES FROM THE VARIOUS BOOTABLE FIX TOOLS**

---

The computer is about 7 years old, here's it's relevant hardware:
Asrock P55 Deluxe3
Nvidia GTX 460
8 gb of ram
Intel Core i5 760, 2.8 GHz

Original disk is 120GB, Toshiba, it has a dual boot with Win7 and Ubuntu 16.04 which was hard to install. I think I first installed Ubuntu 14.04 and only then added the Win7 which created various boot problems but I was able to "fix" them. I also own a laptop with dual win7-ubuntu 14.04.

---

**WINDOWS 7**

[image: Creating USB with Rufus]

First, I tried to install a Windows 7 Professional from a bootable USB. I created a bootable USB and ran it without a problem. Created a partition from half of the drive and chose to install Win7 on it. At one point it says it will restart to continue the installation and I agree (if there is a prompt to agree too, not just information). It restarts, however, when booting I was getting a "no such device XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX..." error and was being booted to grub. Not sure what order, but I tried:

1. I tried using [this boot-repair tool](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/). If I remember correctly, it got rid of the "no such device" problem but led to "Reboot and select proper Boot Device
   or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device" screen.
2. The Windows 7 bootable USB repair, which when completed successfully either didn't change anything or had the exact same result as 1.
3. Through the Win7 bootable usb, using the command prompt I tried doing a bcdboot and bootrec /rebuildbcd, not sure what were the results.

At this point I was rather resigned, but I noticed one thing: *when booting through the USB, I got a message of "Press any key to boot from the USB", however, if I didn't press any button, it would boot me to a working, new Windows 7*

Bizzare. I don't think I created a live USB. I can't say for sure if I went to see if it was on a disk, but I think I did and am fairly certain it was the installation from the disk.

However, I had problems downloading a Win7 image from MS, I torrented one since I have an MSDNAA license for my studies and the working Win7 is legal. I simply decided I'd deal with key issues once I had it installed. Since the ISO wasn't exactly official, I decided to get a Win10 key and an official image.

---

**Windows 10**

I installed the Win10 on the USB drive the same way I did with Win7. I deleted the existing partition, restarted the computer and installed Win10. After the installation exactly the same problem appeared as with the Win7. I tried the same solutions as with Win7 and I can't remember exactly as it was yesterday and I'm dead tired, but I think the solutions and results were largely the same.

And again, I was able to boot into Windows 10 by booting into the USB and not pressing a key.

---

**Clone of Windows 7**

Since I couldn't get a new system to boot correctly, and since it worked, I decided I'd clone my existing Win7.

[image: Here are the drives after the second cloning]

Bear in mind the difference in System Reserved partitions appeared only after attempting to fix it. The size difference in primary partitions existed upon cloning, I assume due to

The MX500 SSD comes with an Acronis True Image for Crucial software. However, the GUI was a bit tedious and confusing to use, so I decided to use Macrium Reflect.

The cloning went as follows:

1. I choose to clone Disk 1
2. I choose the new disk as the recipient
3. I uncheck the Ubuntu partitions
4. I resize the primary partition to be bigger (only on first try, on second try I left it as is)
5. I clone with options Intelligent Sector Copy (meaning only used sectors will be copied, I suspect this is the reason the copied primary partition is smaller) and Enable SSD Trim.

The cloning is successful. After reboot, with both disks present, the computer boots into the original drive. I only see the original boot choices, so I stupidly assume I need to add the boots from the second drive. I don't exactly remember how, but through the command prompt from the win10 installation USB, I add the boot choices to achieve the following:

[image: Notice the sdb1 & sdb2 which wasn't there before]

Windows only boots from sda2 and sdb2 partitions. Notice, that when attempting to fix the boot problems of the original system (long time ago, no idea how or what happened) a boot option was added to the System Reserve partition which, I think, redirects to the boot menu and only sda2 is the proper boot.

When I set the MX500 as the main boot drive and remove all other bootable devices, it simply states:

*"Reboot and select proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device"*

However, if I have a Win7 bootable USB inserted, I can do one of the following:

1. Boot the clone drive, which simply boots to the USB
2. Boot the USB, and upon not pressing any keys, nothing happens (as opposed to previously booting into Win7/10).

Again, I attempt to fix the boot using one of the following methods, I don't remember the order:

1. Win7 boot repair. Upon hitting "Repair current system" it says that there's a boot problem and a prompt appears asking me to agree to fixing the problem and restarting the system. I agree and the action fails. The tool doesn't find a windows OS, I go to the choose a tool screen. The USB system doesn't find a drive, it says "Unknown". I start the command prompt and try: `bcdboot D:\Windows /s C:`. It says the operation succeeded. Nothing changes.
2. I use the boot-repair tool. Doesn't fix anything. Pastebin from it [today](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dxmWMvqSmr), [yesterday, with both disks attached](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RtT2NQjd6H/).
3. I create a bootable USB with the Macrium Reflect Rescue Media

[image: Rescue Media]

I boot into it and it sees the drive and the system and I choose to completely rebuild the boot. Including the MBR, etc. It does so, nothing changes when trying to boot.

This morning I tried to clone the disk without chaning the partition size, I did the following:

1. Both drives are attached.
2. Copy two partitions from original to empty without changing anything.
3. Clone.
4. Restart the computer.
5. Detach original drive, put new drive with clone into it's SATA cable.
6. Start system.

Doesn't work, again, asks to insert a bootable device.

---

Now, I'm desperate. I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas? Only things I think could maybe somehow work better are:

1. Create a clone using Acronis True Image and hope it just works.
2. Do some boot device magic through the command prompt that I just don't know how to do and is a bit beyond my abilities.
3. Reinstall/reset the BIOS which I think may be partly responsible.
4. Find another tool to fix the boot.
5. Install Ubuntu first
6. Clone the entire drive, along with Ubuntu and unused sectors
7. Drive is faulty, check for faultyness.

All suggestions are welcome. I can try and attempt anything, provide any extra information.

---

EDIT: Random things that happened but I don't remember when, updated as I recollect them:

1. Missing boot manager after booting
2. Used Easy BCD 2.3, which resulted in both drives not being bootable. I think boot-repair fixed it.

EDIT2: Interesting developments:

1. Installed Ubuntu 16.04 with no additional shenanigans. It didn't boot again, but I was able to (don't exactly remember how) add an option to my old drives grub to boot that system and it worked. However, if I removed the old disk, it would again boot to the "Reboot and select a proper boot device" screen.
2. **Desperate to fix my problem, I decided to determine if the problem lies in the drive. I took out the SSD in my laptop and attempted to install ubuntu 16.04 on the new drive. Since the laptop uses an EFI partition, when installing I created 3 partitions: 1gb logical efi partition, 245gb primary ext4 partition and a 4gb swap area. After installation I reboot the laptop and the system booted into ubuntu without a problem. This means that the problem either lies in the hardware of my computer or the BIOS.**

Comment: Sounds like you are not setting the boot partition as 'active'.

Comment: Put SSD in caddy and use diskpart on another machine - Make sure you set to active after formatting. Place SSD in original machine and install Windows. Don't worry about drivers just get it to the first windows screen. Shutdown. Install Linux making sure that it is sharing the disk with windows......

Comment: @JohnnyVegas In a caddy? So you're asking me to create a partition on another machine before putting it into the original machine and installing Windows on it? The last time I tried that it refused to use the partition, but I'll try it this time.

Also, not always, but during a large portion of my efforts in when installing the OS-es I'd set the boot partition as 'active'. Either the partition the system itself is on or the separate boot partitions I created.

Also, did you see my last edit? I managed to install and boot into an Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop.

Comment: You have the wrong ideas here - you need to prepare the SSD first - Using diskpart will do this. Forget about partitions etc as they do not matter - Windows install & Ubuntu install will do this for you.

Comment: Diskpart commands are : List disk, select disk x(number from list disk),clean, create partition primary, active, format fs=ntfs quick. Place disk in computer and install windows first, then ubuntu - remember to get ubuntu to share the disk space and to create its own partition automatically (never manually)

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I followed your instructions and the result was the same. I installed media repair from Macrium Reflect to have diskpart on a small usb (it uses win7). I did the following: select disk 0 -> clean -> create partition PRIMARY -> activate -> formatfs=ntfs quick. Placed into computer along with a Win7 installation USB. Installed windows and let installer choose it's own partition (there was only one partition, the one created by diskpart taking up the entire disk).

Comment: @JohnnyVegas It installed fine and at one point of the installation (as it should, I guess) it reboots to continue installation with the booted system. I'll attempt to fix it with various boot repair tools.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Tried fixing it with previously mentioned MR media repair tool. Didn't work. Inserted my old disk, [here's](https://i.imgur.com/ldvHxWj.png) a screen of the partition status. It, again, booted into the "Select a properboot device".

Addendum to previous comment: the installation before the first fix attempt booted to the "Select..." screen as well. I'll try boot-repair next.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Here's an interesting thing. Using the Win7 install USB, via the command prompt I tried fixing the BCD. Using things like bcdedit.exe /fixmbr ... /rebuildbcd. The /rebuildbcd sees the win7 installation, but when I accept to add it, it says "The requested system device cannot be found" and it fails. I can normally access C: and the files in c:\boot\. When I try to manually repair the bcd, at one point or another the same exact problem appears.

BCDBoot C:\Windows /s C: works and succeeds, but doesn't change anything. \boot contains BCD.BACKUP.000X and BCD.bak. and language files

Comment: Ignore everything you have done and just run through windows 7 setup - Don't do anything outside the install. I fail to see why you are going through stuff trying to fix a problem that just setting up windows 7 will clear.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Because it doesn't work. I did every step in what you wrote and the problem remains. It simply goes to a screen that says "Select a proper boot device". It's a clean install, following all those steps, cleaning the disk, formatting it to ntfs, putting into pc, installing win7 and letting it choose everything by itself. It reboots while installing and it just doesn't boot to the SSD and instead it follows the boot list and boots the USB win7 installation.

Comment: If it reboots whilst installing then the SSD may be faulty. I dont think you mentioned this but it's the biggest clue to your issue.

Comment: I appreciate the write up , but theres NO CLEAR question here. Please try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a "gparted live" dvd.

Boot from the dvd.

Make a single partition for the entire ssd disc.

format the ssd as ntfs

power off the pc

disconnect all hard disc drives, except the ssd, from the motherboard.  leave the ssd connected.

insert your bootable windows install media and install windows on the ssd

remove your install media

now, restart the pc.  it will be forced to try to boot from the ssd.

if you can boot into windows, the rest is easy.

get into your bios and in the "boot order" section, make sure that the ssd is positioned before the other hard drives.

now, boot from ubuntu bootable install media.  ubuntu will guide you through the process of making your ssd dual-bootable.

power off the pc and reconnect your cables for your other hard drives to the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues cloning from Maxtor 400 MB HD to MX500.
Size of used data on MX is 150 GB while source is 50 GB
Will not boot
I even cloned with Startech duplicator several times.
Finally did a boot with Windows CD and installed window from scratch and all working good.